# error loading UIWebView in storyboard

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, storyboard, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to load a UIWebVIew from within my storyboard but I am getting a SIGABRT error on this line of code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_show" ofType:nil]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this instead:
`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_show"]`

The `pathForResource` method is used to get the path to local files.